# CURL HTTP HEADER coding

Tags: php, curl

hope someone can help with this code ...
I have a PHP CURL code to post to URL ... the issue is

- If I posted a text with single line then the text will delivered
- If I posted a text with multiple lines then it will not be deliver

> Blockquote

```
curl_setopt_array($curl, [
        CURLOPT_URL => "http://example.com/sendText",
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
        CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
        CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
        CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,
        CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
        CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "POST",
        CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => '{ "sessionName":"'.$row_ch["phone"].'","number": "'.$row_outmsg["tonum"].'","text":"'.$row_outmsg["body"].'"}',
        CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => [
            "Accept: application/json",
            "Content-Type: application/json"
          ],
            ]);
```

Can some help me fixing the multi lines posting? .. please .

Comment: `If I posted a text with single line then the text will delivered` what text?

Comment: Probably due to the fact, that you are manually assembling JSON here. DON’T DO THAT. Create & fill the appropriate PHP data structure, and then use `json_encode` on that.

Comment: Any text created and saved to mysql database .. @PhúcHậuTrần

Comment: do you have an example? . @CBroe

Comment: Create an associative array with those keys and values you have there in your JSON.

Comment: I mean when you said text did you mean this $row_outmsg["body"]

Answer (score 0):

The json with new line is incorrect format

Use

```
CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => json_encode(array(
    "sessionName" => $row_ch["phone"],
    "number" => $row_outmsg["tonum"],
    "text" => $row_outmsg["body"]
))
```